# How can I call a PHP variable within a HTML Textbox Tag?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, nested

Apparently, I can't produce an output in this code due to the error Undefined Variable. It makes it difficult because I can't test whether or not my condition statement works. @_@ Please help. :( Am I using Nested IFs right?

> 

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkform(form){

if (form.bp.value=="") {
alert("Please enter basic pay!");
form.bp.focus;
return false;
}
else if (form.payper.value==" ") {
alert("Please enter Payroll Period!");
form.payper.focus;
return false; 
}
else if (form.stat.value==" ") {
alert("Please enter Employee Status!");
form.stat.focus;
return false; 
}
else
return true;
}
</script>
<body bgcolor = "black" >
<center>
<title> Tax Calculator </title>



<style>
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
font-family:"Arial";
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
font-size:12px;
}
th
{
background-color:crimson;
color:white;
padding:5px;
}
td
{
background-color:gray;
color:white;
font-style:italic
</style>



<form action="d2.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this)">
<br> <br>
<table>
<th colspan=10>Employee Tax Calculator</th>

<tr><td>Basic Pay: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="bp"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Payroll Period: </td>
<td><select name = "payper" >
    <option value=" "> -Select- </option>
    <option value="Daily"> Daily </option>
    <option value="Weekly"> Weekly </option>
    <option value="Semi"> Semi-Monthly </option>
    <option value="Monthly"> Monthly </option>
    </select>
</td>

<tr><td>Employee Status: </td>
<td><select name = "stat" >
    <option value=" "> -Select- </option>
    <option value="Z"> Z </option>
    <option value="S"> S / ME </option>
    <option value="ME1"> ME1 / S1 </option>
    <option value="ME2"> ME2 / S2 </option>
    <option value="ME3"> ME3 / S3 </option>
    <option value="ME4"> ME4 / S4 </option>
    </select>
</td>


<tr><td>Withholding Tax: </td>
<td> <?php echo $wtax; ?></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="Submit" value="Calculate" name="Calculate">

</form>

<?php

IF (isset($_POST['Calculate'])) {

$bp = $_POST['bp'];
$payper = $_POST['payper'];
$stat = $_POST['stat'];
$trate = 0;
$btax= 0;
$incomeb = 0;

$wtax = ($bp - $incomeb) * $trate + $btax;


IF ($payper == "Daily" && $stat == "Z") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb== 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb == 0) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=33 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 1.65;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=99) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 8.25;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=231) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 28.05;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 462) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 74.26;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 825) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 165.02;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1650) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 412.54;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Daily" && $stat == "S") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 165) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=198 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 1.65;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 264) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 8.25;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 396) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 28.05;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 627) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 74.26;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 990) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 165.02;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1815) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 412.54;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Daily" && $stat == "ME1") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=248) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=281 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 1.65;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 347) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 8.25;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 479) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 28.05;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=710) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 74.26;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=1073) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 165.02;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=1898) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 412.54;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Daily" && $stat == "ME2") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=330) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=363 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 1.65;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=429) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 8.25;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=561) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 28.05;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=792) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 74.26;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=1155) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 165.02;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=1980) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 412.54;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Daily" && $stat == "ME3") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 413) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=446 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 1.65;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=512) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 8.25;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 644) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 28.05;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 875) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 74.26;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1238) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 165.02;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2063) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 412.54;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Daily" && $stat == "ME4") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=1 ) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 495) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 528 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 1.65;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 594) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 8.25;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 726) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 28.05;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 957) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 74.26;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1320) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 165.02;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2145) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 412.54;
    }   
}


IF ($payper == "Weekly" && $stat == "Z") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb == 0) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 192 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 9.62;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 577) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 48.08;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1346) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 163.46;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2692) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 432.69;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4808) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 961.54;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 9615) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 2403.85;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Weekly" && $stat == "S") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 962) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1154 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 9.62;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1538) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 48.08;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2308) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 163.46;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3654) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 432.69;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5769) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 961.54;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 10577) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 2403.85;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Weekly" && $stat == "ME1") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1442) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1635) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 9.62;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2019) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 48.08;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2788) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 163.46;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4135) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 432.69;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6250) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 961.54;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 11058) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 2403.85;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Weekly" && $stat == "ME2") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1923) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2115 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 9.62;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2500) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 48.08;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3269) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 163.46;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4615) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 432.69;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6731) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 961.54;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 11538) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 2403.85;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Weekly" && $stat == "ME3") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2404) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2596) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 9.62;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2981) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 48.08;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3750) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 163.46;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5096) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 432.69;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 7212) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 961.54;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 12019) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 2403.85;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Weekly" && $stat == "ME4") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2885) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3077) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 9.62;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3462) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 48.08;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4231) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 163.46;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5577) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 432.69;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 7692) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 961.54;
    }
    ELSE IF($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=12500) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 2403.85;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Semi" && $stat == "Z") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb == 0) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 417 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 20.83;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1250) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 104.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2917) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 354.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5833) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 937.50;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 10417) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 2083.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 20833) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 5208.33;
    }   
}
IF ($payper == "Semi" && $stat == "S") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2083) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2500 ) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 20.83;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3333) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 104.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5000) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 354.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 7917) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 937.50;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 12500) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 2083.33;
    }
    ELSE IF($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 22917) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 5208.33;
    }   

}

IF ($payper == "Semi" && $stat == "ME1") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3215) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 3542) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 20.83;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=4375) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 104.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=6042) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 354.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=8958) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 937.50;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 13542) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 2083.33;
    }
    ELSE IF($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=23958) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 5208.33;
    }   
}


IF ($payper == "Semi" && $stat == "ME2") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4617) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4583) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 20.83;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5417) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 104.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 7083) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 354.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 10000) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 937.50;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 14583) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 2083.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 25000) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 5208.33;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Semi" && $stat == "ME3") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5208) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5625) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 20.83;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6458) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 104.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 8125) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 354.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 11042) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 937.50;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 15625) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 2083.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 26042) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 5208.33;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Semi" && $stat == "ME4") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6250) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6667) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 20.83;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 7500) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 104.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 9167) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 354.17;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 12083) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 937.50;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 16667) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 2083.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 27083) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 5208.33;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Monthly" && $stat == "Z") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb == 0) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 833) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 41.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 2500) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 208.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5833) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 708.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=11667) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 1875.00;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 20833) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 4166.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 41667) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 10416.67;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Monthly" && $stat == "S") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 4167) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 5000) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 41.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6667) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 208.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 10000) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 708.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=15833) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 1875.00;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 25000) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 4166.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 45833) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 10416.67;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Monthly" && $stat == "ME1") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 6250) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 7083) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 41.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 8750) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 208.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 12083) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 708.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=17917) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 1875.00;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 27083) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 4166.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 47917) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 10416.67;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Monthly" && $stat == "ME2") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 8333) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 9167) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 41.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 10833) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 208.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 14167) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 708.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 20000) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 1875.00;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 29167) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 4166.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 50000) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 10416.67;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Monthly" && $stat == "ME3") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 10417) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 11250) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 41.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 12917) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 208.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 16250) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 708.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 22083) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 1875.00;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 31250) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 4166.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 52083) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 10416.67;
    }   
}

IF ($payper == "Monthly" && $stat == "ME4") {
    IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 1) {
    $trate = .0;
    $btax = 0;  
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 12500) {
    $trate = .05;
    $btax = 0;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 13333) {
    $trate = .10;
    $btax = 41.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 15000) {
    $trate = .15;
    $btax = 208.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 18333) {
    $trate = .20;
    $btax = 708.33;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=24167) {
    $trate = .25;
    $btax = 1875.00;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >= 33333) {
    $trate = .30;
    $btax = 4166.67;
    }
    ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=54167) {
    $trate = .32;
    $btax = 10416.67;
    }   
}

echo '<font color="white">' . $wtax . '</font>';

}

?> 

<br><br>

<div id="footer" size= 8  style="background-color:#656565; clear:both; text-align:center; font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;color:white">
<b>Copyright @ Eun Mendoza</b></div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont capitalize your `if`s and `else`s. and use `elseif` not `else if`

Comment: so does that mean in using IF and ELSE statements in PHP, it's somewhat case sensitive? >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `if` and `else` should be lowercase.  `elseif` vs `else if` doesn't matter if you are using curly braces.
90% of your if statement will never happen.

```
IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=33 ) {
  ...
}
ELSE IF ($bp >= $incomeb && $incomeb >=99) {
 ...
}
```

if $incomeb >= 99, it's >= 33, so the first condition will happen.  Any scenario where the else conditions are met, the one before it is met too, so the else won't be called.

As for the undefined variable, figure out what line number it is on, I'm not going to read through your whole thing to find it.

Comment: Btw. `elseif` is a tiny bit faster than `else if`

Comment: Oh thanks much will do! The undefined variable is not in the php actually, I'm trying to use my $wtax as an output in my html text box.  <tr><td>Withholding Tax: </td>
<td> <?php echo $wtax; ?></td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score -1):

Move the PHP calculation part to the top of the page. You can't expect a variable to have a value when it's not even defined in the code yet.

Also, like @chillNut said, `if` and `else` are lowercase, and `elseif` should be used instead of `else if` in PHP.

Comment: @PHPglue Did someone say they don't? Thanks for the downvote, btw.